# What is contact means asked for in HKSAR Department of Health Health Declaration Form

Tags: covid-19, hong-kong

HKSAR Department of Health
Health Declaration Form https://hdf.chp.gov.hk/dhehd/hdf-hkia.jsp?lang=en-us is required to be filled out and submitted online by a person arriving at Hong Kong.

The last section of it is called Contact means.

Does it ask for my contact information in Hong Kong? If yes, I don't know how to answer these mandatory questions. I don't plan to stay in Hong Kong as it is just a stop in the middle of travel.

[image]

Comment: What is the exact purpose of your arrival in Hong Kong? Ex: are you flying to another country with a layover in Hong Kong?

Comment: To the mainland

Answer (score 9):

The form is asking for your contact information during your stay in Hong Kong.

The following screenshot is the same section of the form in Chinese:[image]

I will not translate the form word-for-word but can confirm it asks for one's phone number, email (optional), and address while in Hong Kong. It is possible to put the address of a hotel in the Building/Estate/Street box.

> If yes, I don't know how to answer the questions which are required to. I don't plan to stay in Hong Kong, and it is just a stop in the middle of travel.

It turns out you might not need to worry about this form at all - as of 28 Jan 2023, [it is optional to fill in](https://www.coronavirus.gov.hk/eng/inbound-travel.html):

> ## Persons arriving from overseas places
>
> [...] May declare test result via the voluntary electronic Health Declaration Form

The requirement is also not applicable to those in transit:

> ## Other Points to Note
>
> The above pre-departure requirements are not applicable to the following persons:
>
> - A person who is in transit/transfer in Hong Kong; [...]